# Random DNS errors only when one computer is using one network

Tags: windows-7, dns, home-networking, wireless-router, internet-connection

I have an issue with my laptop's internet connection.

We've got a home network with about 5 computers and ipods, ipads, etc. Among all of these devices, my laptop (Windows 7) seems to be the only one that constantly gets random DNS errors.  The weird thing is that our home network is the only place where this is the case. At school, the library, a restaurant, or friends' houses it will connect fine, but in our network it just won't. When I turn the computer and it finds the network I have to wait long periods of time before I can get internet access. If I am browsing the web, sites will normally take forever just to connect before they can load. If they load it will usually be some basic view with no images or styles displayed. Usually however, I am directed to a DNS look up error page or a "google chrome could not find that page." This happens with all browsers on my computer. Any help would be appreciated.

I have already tried the following...

**-Turn router off and on.**

**Using Google's and Open DNS' servers**

**-Type into command prompt:** 
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
net stop "dns client"
net start "dns client"
*[restarted computer]*

**-Typed into command prompt:**
netsh int ip reset reset.log
netsh winsock reset catalog
*[restarted computer*

**-Downloaded Winsockfix**

Comment: Which O/s installed on your laptop?

Comment: try changing the dns to 8.8.8.8 · 8.8.4.4 are the public dns from google https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what in the world is going on here, but if I had this problem, I'd be using
Wireshark (wireshark.org) to see what is happening.  It is a packet sniffer.  Download it and use it.  Ultimately, interpretation of what the packets are showing isn't for the faint of heart, but one can save what packets you capture to a file, & have someone else review it. Maybe it is possible to give some tips to you here of what to look for.... like unanswered DNS requests.  There are some potential security issues with handing the captured packets file off to just anyone.

You'll need to run Wireshark as an admin, unless, IIRC for Windows (I'm mainly a Linux guy), you install WinPcap, which also gets installed along with Wireshark, to allow "anyone" to do sniffing.

Once Wireshark is running do "Capture->Options->select interface->start".  All the other default options in the options dialog are probably fine.  Capture for a few minutes while you experience/force the DNS issue.  Then "capture->stop" then "file->save" and/or scroll through your captured packets.

Another question for you.  Is this issue happening while using a wireless interface?  Try using a wired interface, just to collect another data point.  Also Wireshark using wireless is impacted in a major way 'cause you can't capture in what is called "promiscuous" mode, which *IS* the real networking technical term commonly used which means it listens to everything on the network.  Almost all Microsoft wireless drivers don't allow promiscuous mode on wireless networks to prevent hacking on open wireless networks, but for your DNS question it's likely one doesn't need promiscuous mode to see what is or isn't going on with your laptop ... but use it if you can, like when on a wired network.

I'll watch this issue to help further.

Comment: I haven't used a wired connection in a while, but when I did I think it was the same issue. I've downloaded Wireshark but am unsure what the data means.